# Как проверить, существует ли запись в таблице sql, если существует вернуть, если нет вставить запись

Tags: sql

Вот пример

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Users WHERE FirstName = 'John' AND LastName = 'Smith' )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Users (FirstName, LastName) VALUES ('John', 'Smith')
END
```

В данном запросе мне не нравится то, что записи select не возвращаются, если же написать else, то придется еще раз делать запрос на sekect, можно как то избежать 2 запросов на select?

Comment: какую СУБД вы используете? Ответ от этого зависит.

Comment: @RomanKonoval, postgress

Comment: можно использовать конструкцию `merge`